# candle.exe access is denied

Tags: wix, installation, heat

I'm trying to create an installer using the WIX installer. first, I created a new WIX installer in VS 2015 and then I created an additional wxs file using the heat command.
Now I would like to add the generated file to the WIX project using the candle.exe command but I'm getting an "access is denied" error when executing the candle command.

(heat command: "%WIX%\bin\heat.exe" dir "D:\Dev\WIX\Build\bin\release" -dr Build -cg Build -gg -g1 -sf -srd -sreg bin-var "var.Build" -out FilesHeat.wxs)

candle command: "%WIX%\bin\candle.exe" FilesHeat.wxs Product.wxs -dversion=2.0.3.1 -dBuild=d:\Dev\WIX\Build

What can be the reason for it?

Comment: Verify that the user running `candle.exe` command has RW to the involved directories. Ideally, log in as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the `HeatGenerated.wxs`
2. Build  - it will give you error, then refresh project and you will see the new `heatgeneraded.wsx` - include it in the project
3. Build again and profit.